# Units and zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_7[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I found all zero divisors and units in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_7[i] = \{a + bi: a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_7\}$. I did this by writing out all $49$ elements and then examining each of the elements. My question is if there is an easier more systematic way to do this problem. How would one, for example, do this if on had a bigger ring like $\mathbb{Z}_{100}[i]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_m[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}_m[x]/(x^2+1)$ and so is a field iff $m$ is prime and $x^2+1$ is irreducible mod $m$, that is, has no roots mod $m$.

If $m$ is not prime, then $m=ab$ and $a$ and $b$ are zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

If $m$ is prime but $x^2+1$ has roots $a,b$ mod $m$, then $x^2+1=(x-a)(x-b)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_m[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_m$ has many obvious zero divisors.

Finally, if $m$ is prime then $x^2+1$ has no roots mod $m$ iff $m \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.

Answer (score 1):

The ring $(\mathbb{Z}/7)[i]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(7)$, which is a field with $49$ elements. Hence all non-zero elements are units, and we have no non-trivial zero divisors. In general, if $q\equiv 3\bmod 4$ is a prime,
$\mathbb{Z}[i]/(q)$ is a field with $q^2$ elements.

Comment: How do you get that isomorphism? Is this in general true?

Comment: Yes, see page $5$ [here](http://www.mathstat.concordia.ca/faculty/cdavid/MATH470/W2016/sol4.pdf).